# If TextInputLayout has display error, the button should disable its activity

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I have a question about how to disable the button functionality when the text input layout have set the error.

Here is the interface I have created.

[image: here is the interface that I have created]

Comment: use addTextChangedListener

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your button xml:

```
android:enabled="false"
```

and then enable it back once you're done with validating signUp Fields.

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable or disable button on the base of your validation so try this code.

```
username.addTextChangedListener { charSequence  ->
            signup.isEnabled=true
                          
        }
signup.setOnClickListener {
            var error:Boolean= false
            //your condition for validations on fields
            if(username.text.toString().isNullOrEmpty()){
                error=true
            }
            if(error){
              signup.isEnabled = false
            }else{
                //api call
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
yourButton.isEnabled = false
```

or

```
yourButton.isClickable = false
```

right after you decide that one of your input fields is not valid